# Requester IP in Node.js Application is different from the IP received in Nginx

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I'm building a node.JS application, using  Sails.js, that demands a validation method based on user's IP and a token. My application receives the requester ip's and validate with a document stored by another application. 
I'm facing a issue which sometimes my application seen to assign the wrong IP value to the requester.

I have the following validation method:

```
validate: function (req, res) {
//get requester IP
  ip = (req.headers['x-real-ip'] || 
            req.connection.remoteAddress || 
            req.socket.remoteAddress ||
            req.connection.socket.remoteAddress):
  valid = false;
  Validation.findOne({token: req.param("token")}).exec(function findVal(err, validation){
     if (validation.ip == ip){
         console.log("Correct IP");
      }
      else{
         console.log("Wrong IP!");
         console.log("token:" + req.param("token"));
         console.log("Received:" + ip);
         console.log("Expected:" + validation.ip);
      }
   });
 }
```

Occasionally I get a "Wrong IP" output, even if the requester IP is correct.
Checking the MongoDB documents and Nginx log, I believe that my application sometimes overrides the ip value with a new requester's IP.

```
-- Nodejs application log in a real scenario

Wrong IP!
token: example123
Received: 150.xx.xx.50
Expected: 186.xx.xx.106

Correct IP

Correct IP
```

the request below refers to the Wrong Ip error described above. In the request received by Nginx, the ip is correct, while the value processed by the node application is wrong. The IP value received by node is the same as the third request in the log below

```
-- Nginx access log

186.xx.xx.106 -- [15/Oct/2014:22:10:57 +0000] 
"GET /validate?token=example123 HTTP/1.1" 200 2 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US;  ) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1025.166 Safari/535.19" "-"

 [other request]

 150.xx.xx.50 -- [15/Oct/2014:22:10:59 +0000] 
"GET /validate?token=notTheSameValue HTTP/1.1" 200 2 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US;  ) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1025.166 Safari/535.19" "-"
```

So, I have the following scenario:

```
[request 1][Failed]
-> Nginx received request from IP 186.xx.xx.106 with param: token = example123
-> Node application received request from IP 150.xx.xx.50 with param: token = example123

[request 2][OK]
data ommited

[request 3][OK]
-> Nginx received request from IP 150.xx.xx.50 with param: token = notTheSameValue 
-> Node application received request from IP 150.xx.xx.50 with param: token = notTheSameValue
```

I've already double checked all the values created in the mongodb documents,  which I use to validate the requester IP.

Does anyone have any idea about what is causing this issue? Maybe something with the method to get the requester IP? I appreciate any help.

Comment: Do you know for sure that the user has static IP address?

Comment: Also, you said that node receives different IP from nginx but from the access log it looks like node receives the same IP as nginx.

Comment: @slebetman yes, I'm sure that the user has static Ip address.
I think wasn't clear about the node application receiving differente IP address. 
if you check the three requests, the first was received in nginx with the ip address 186.xx.xx.106, but node processed it with the ip 150.xx.xx.50. In fact, there is a request from the ip 150.xx.xx.50 at nginx, but not with the parameter token: example123. I'll update my examples to make it clearer. Thanks.